# Pandas df with multiple operator OR statement

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function where one passes a pandas df and it will return Boolean a 1 or 0 based on if some conditions are met.

Can you use multiple OR statements using [Pythons built in operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.or_)? For example I need to see if ***3 conditions are met in the dataframe row*** but the `operator` can only take 2 vars. My testing with Pytest on this function this doesn't work. Thanks for any advice or pseudo code.

```
import operator
import pandas as pd


def fault_finder(df):
    df['flag'] = operator.or_( # <-- 1st operator statement
        (df['temp1'] >= df['temp2'])

        # verify operating state 2
        & (df['free_clg_signal'] > .2)
        & (df['mechanical_clg_signal'] < .1),  # OR

        operator.or_( # <-- 2nd operator statement
        # verify operating state 3
        (df['temp1'] >= df['temp2'])
        & (df['mechanical_clg_signal'] > .01)
        & (df['free_clg_signal'] == .2),  # OR

        # verify operating state 4
        (df['temp1'] >= df['temp2'])
        & (df['mechanical_clg_signal'] > .01)
        & (df['free_clg_signal'] > .9)
        )
    ).astype(int)

    return df
```

Comment: No, you can not do that using the built in `operator.or_`. You can however nest them like you have, or use `x | y | z`

Comment: can you post an answer what that looks like in pseudo code format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.logical_or.reduce`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logical_or.html):

```
def fault_finder(df):
    df['flag'] = np.logical_or.reduce([
        (df['temp1'] >= df['temp2'])

        # verify operating state 2
        & (df['free_clg_signal'] > .2)
        & (df['mechanical_clg_signal'] < .1),

        # verify operating state 3
        (df['temp1'] >= df['temp2'])
        & (df['mechanical_clg_signal'] > .01)
        & (df['free_clg_signal'] == .2),

        # verify operating state 4
        (df['temp1'] >= df['temp2'])
        & (df['mechanical_clg_signal'] > .01)
        & (df['free_clg_signal'] > .9)
        
    ]).astype(int)

    return df
```

Or `|` and parentheses:

```
def fault_finder(df):
    df['flag'] = ((
        (df['temp1'] >= df['temp2'])

        # verify operating state 2
        & (df['free_clg_signal'] > .2)
        & (df['mechanical_clg_signal'] < .1))
    
       |

       ( # verify operating state 3
        (df['temp1'] >= df['temp2'])
        & (df['mechanical_clg_signal'] > .01)
        & (df['free_clg_signal'] == .2))

       |
        
        (# verify operating state 4
        (df['temp1'] >= df['temp2'])
        & (df['mechanical_clg_signal'] > .01)
        & (df['free_clg_signal'] > .9))
        
       ).astype(int)

    return df
```

Example:

```
fault_finder(df)

   temp1  temp2  free_clg_signal  mechanical_clg_signal  flag
0      1      0              0.3                   0.05     1
1      2      4              0.2                   1.00     0
2      3      0              1.0                   1.00     1
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `operator.or_` can only take two arguments. So if you have more than two boolean masks, you'll need to nest calls to `operator.or_`. But why not use `|`?

```
import pandas as pd

mask1 = pd.Series([True, False, True, True, False])
mask2 = pd.Series([False, False, False, True, True])
mask3 = pd.Series([True, False, False, True, True])

out = operator.or_(
    operator.or_(mask1, mask2),
    mask3
)

# Note that you can't do operator.or_(mask1, mask2, mask3)
# because operator.or_ only takes 2 arguments
```

which is equivalent to the less verbose:

```
out = mask1 | mask2 | mask3
```

You could also use a functional approach; something like:

```
import functools
functools.reduce(operator.or_, [mask1, mask2, mask3])
```

If the boolean series are in one dataframe, you could also use [`pd.DataFrame.any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) with an axis argument.

```
df = pd.concat([mask1, mask2, mask3], axis=1)
out = df.any(axis=1)
```

or [`numpy.any`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.any.html):

```
import numpy as np
np.any([mask1, mask2, mask3], axis=0)
```

but numpy approaches will return an array, not a `pd.Series`.